# how to create a file or folder based on other command output

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script to configure a router based on linux remotely. The first step is to obtain a serial number of the device which I want to:

1. Create a folder of the same name as the serial number
2. Create a text file with the serial number
3. Put a line containing this serial number to the config file

Task 2 is the easiest - `mnf_info -s > sn.txt`, but how do I extract the actual name and pass it do `mkdir` and `sed` after that?

Also, do you have any clue how to change password remotely without any interaction - I do not have expect command on that device, so I have to do it otherwise. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Krzysztof

Comment: How do you run the script? Show your unfinished script in the question, formatted as a code block.

Comment: Please try to stick to one problem per question. The password question is a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

You may save the output of a command via `variable=$(command)`. So in your case:

```
serial="$(mnf_info -s)"
mkdir "$serial"
echo "$serial" > "$serial"/sn.txt
```

Now if you want to run that locally saved script remotely, you may save the above lines (locally) in `myscript`, then use

```
ssh user@remote.machine "bash" <myscript
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ssh $i <<'EOF'
ser=$(mnf_info -s)
mkdir $ser
mnf_info -s >sn.txt
sed -i '1i $ser'  configfile
EOF

Here we saving serial number in variable and later using to creating directory and add variable content in config file

This may help you
```

Comment: Thanks - it worked for me perfectly.

Comment: Can you please vote for my answer